# Is it possible to have youtube embed code inside JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Can I have youtube embed code inside my JSON have it the video to display once the content of JSON is being used?

```
[{

    "title": "New World Sound & Thomas Newson - Flute (Original Mix)",
    "embed": "<iframe width="
    560 " height="
    315 " src="
    https: //www.youtube.com/embed/e-U1lj57pv8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>"

}]
```

Comment: Youtube embed codes can go into JSON, but this is not valid JSON. Newlines need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

Since JSON is meant for data, it would be better to structure your data like

```
{
  "name": "Beautiful cats",
  "keywords": ["cats", "cat", "beautiful", "funny"],
  "contentUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/e-U1lj57pv8" 
}
```

When read by the client, it could choose to display the contentUrl within an `iframe`.

Think of using JSON not only in a browser-scenario: Then the iframe would be pretty useless.